# Question regarding recursive data structures in C

Tags: c, recursion, data-structures

If I have a recursive structure

```
typdef struct {
    int foo;
    baz* bar;
} baz;

baz* myStruct;
```

How would I access the `foo` value of `bar` in `myStruct`?

In a "guess-and-test" manner, I've tried

```
myStruct->bar.foo;
(*myStruct->bar).foo;
(*(*(myStruct)->bar).foo);
```

and a few other combinations, but I always get an error.

Obviously, my knowledge regarding the subject is limited. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: C isn't really a "guess and test" kind of language. It's one where you read a book and it explains things. C itself is quirky, but not that tricky most of the time.

Comment: @lurker This was an error on my part. I meant for `myStruct` to be a pointer.

Comment: Then `myStruct->bar->foo since `baz` is a pointer to a struct. Or dereference as `(*(myStruct->bar)).foo`. You do need to say what your error is that you're getting because your self-referencing declaration isn't quite right (as indicated in one of the answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to forward declare `baz`:

```
typedef struct baz {
    int foo;
    struct baz* bar;
} baz;
```

(note the extra `baz`).

Then (with your modified question) you can do:

`myStruct->bar->foo`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to write `myStruct->bar->foo`? `bar` is a pointer, so you need to dereference it using `->` to get to its inner `foo`.

Comment: This was my original thought, but I got the error `error: request for member 'foo' in something not a structure or union`

Comment: [I don't believe you](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/FtBDvNd).

Comment: I keep getting `[Program exited with exit code -11]`. I don't really know how the web tool works, but where do I view the printed output?

Comment: That is the output, the variable isn't initialized. Your claim was that it doesn't compile, and it does, as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

As `myStruct` is not a pointer, any property access uses `.`.

As `bar` is a pointer you must use `->`.

Combined:

```c
myStruct.bar->foo
```

This is all based on the immediate type you're trying to "navigate" through.

As in:

```c
baz* bar = myStruct.bar;
```

This is a valid assignment, pointer to pointer, so logically the next step is `->`.

Comment: Apologies on my end, I meant for `myStruct` to be a pointer. I've edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Then it's `->` twice, same rules apply.